# How to change background color of a cell if it is edited after a specific duration?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a google spreadsheet which we use to feed inventory purchase and issue data. The only problem is my staff can manipulate purchased quantity, prices and other variables at a later date. I want that if they enter the data in a cell and try to edit it whenever after 12 hours of entering the data, the cell should get highlighted. If possible, the cell should not highlight if I edit the data.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to have a column when this data is entered (if the data is added with a google form, then you are already set to go on that front). At that point all you need is a `onEdit` triggered function that fetches that timestamp, does `var curTime = new Date()` and then check what is the difference between them, and if it's greater than 12 hours you do a `e.range.setBackground('red')` or whatever color you wish (remember that the function must have `e` defined like `function checker(e)`).

Having it ignore edits done by you is also simple, just have an a simple

```
var editUser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
if (editUser == 'myEmail@gmail.com`)
  return 1;
```

and it will stop the script if the session users email matches your own.

For future reference please also provide what code you have so far, as currently we don't know what research you have done so far, what worked and what did not. Remember — here you won't get someone to write the program for you, only solve issues you have with code you already have.